# Triggering a Backbone.js event when the current date changes

Tags: javascript, date, backbone.js, backbone-events

Is there a simple way to trigger a Backbone.js event when the current date (just the day, not the time) changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a better idea than checking regularly:

```
var lastCheckedDate = new Date();
setInterval(function () {
    var d = new Date();
    //TODO: check whether the day in d and lastCheckedDate are the same or not
    //TODO: if not, trigger event
    lastCheckedDate = d;
}, 10000); //this will check in every 10 seconds
```

Comment: curious -- what's the point in polling every 10 seconds if it's a matter of evaluating the day? wouldn't it be better to determine the duration up front, delay the triggering of the event with a setTimeout call and then re-init that function with another setTimeout with 86400?

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I was hoping to avoid using setTimeout in favour of a more event-driven approach, but considering I really just need to know when the date changes, I don't want to create an entire model just for one simple feature. I'll probably implement Nirvana's approach. Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 4):

So, the answer to the question - there is no *simple* way without rolling your own solution.

That said, the implementation isn't too bad.

The idea here is that you have a model with a 'day' property. Upon initializing the model, we'll invoke an initializer that will determine the duration till 'midnight tomorrow'. Right after midnight, the setTimeout will get called which will update the model's 'day' property. In the view itself, we listen for a change for the 'day' property. Once the property is updated, we'll re-initialize the method that changes the date. This way there's no polling, and your events will be triggered once the date changes.

Of course there are numerous ways you could broadcast the update - i.e. explicitly trigger the event as opposed to `set`ing the property -- but here's the code for what I've described above:

**Model**

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        var d = new Date();
        return {
            day: d.getDay()
        }
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, '_init_date_trigger');
        this._init_date_trigger();
    },
    _init_date_trigger: function(){
        var now = new Date();
        var midnightTomorrow = new Date();
        midnightTomorrow.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
        midnightTomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var msTillTomorrow = midnightTomorrow - now + 1;
        var me = this;
        console.log("date will be changed in " + msTillTomorrow);
        setTimeout(function(){
            me.set("day", new Date().getDay());
            me._init_date_trigger();
        }, msTillTomorrow);
    }
})
```

**View**

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template("The day is: <span class='day'> <%= day %> </span>"),
    initialize: function(){
        this.model.on("change:day", this.render);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Implementation**

```
var myModel = new Model();
var myView = new View({model: myModel});
$("#example").html( myView.render().el );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KGzt/4/

Comment: Using `setTimeout` is definitely better than `setInterval` in my answer. Get my +1.

Answer (score 2):

You may create constructor that extends Backbone Events like this:

```
var Clocks = function(){};

_.extend(Clocks.prototype, Backbone.Events, {

  start: function () {
    this.timer = setInterval(_.bind(this.tick, this), 1000);
    return this;
  },

  tick: function () {
    this.trigger('tick', new Date)
  },

  stop: function () {
    this.timer && clearInterval(this.timer);
    return this;
  }

});
```

And then use it in backbone model to update it attributes:

```
var ClocksModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: function () {
    var date = new Date
    return {
      date: date.getDate(),
      seconds: date.getSeconds()
    }
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.clocks = new Clocks;
    this.clocks.on('tick', this.updateDate, this)
  },

  updateDate: function (date) {
    this.set('date', date.getDate())
    this.set('seconds', date.getSeconds())
  },

  start: function () {
    this.clocks.start();
    return this;
  },

  stop: function () {
    this.clock.stop();
    return this;
  }

});
```

Then you'll be able to:

```
clocks = new ClocksModel;
clocks
  .on('change:seconds', function(model, newSeconds) {
    console.log('seconds changed to ', newSeconds)
  })
  .on('change:date', function(model, newDate) {
    console.log('date changed to', newDate)
  })
  .start()
```